# Quebrar página mPdf utilizando view

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

Estou utilizando o mPdf gerando o pdf direto através de uma view pois utilizando os métodos via php não consegui fazer o css da minha página funcionar corretamente

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('contrato', array('desconto' => $desconto,
                                                'codigoAluno' => $codigoAluno,
                                                'qtdeParcelas' => $qtdeParcelas,
                                                'vencimento' => $vencimento,
                                                'cargaHoraria' => $cargaHoraria,
                                                'valorEntrada' => $valorEntrada,
                                                'valorComDesconto' => $valorComDesconto,
                                                'parcelaComDesconto' => $parcelaComDesconto,
                                                'valorSemDesconto' => $valorSemDesconto,
                                                'parcelaSemDesconto' => $parcelaSemDesconto,
                                                'pacote' => $pacote,
                                                'dataInicio' => $dataInicio,
                                                'razaoSocial' => $razaoSocial,
                                                'nomeFantasia' => $nomeFantasia,
                                                'cnpj' => $cnpj,
                                                'telefoneContratado' => $telefoneContratado,
                                                'enderecoContratado' => $enderecoContratado,
                                                'nomeContratante' => $nomeContratante,
                                                'cepContratante' => $cepContratante,
                                                'nascimentoContratante' => $nascimentoContratante,
                                                'enderecoContratante' => $enderecoContratante,
                                                'telefoneContratante' => $telefoneContratante,
                                                'rgContratante' => $rgContratante,
                                                'cpfContratante' => $cpfContratante,
                                                'nomeRepresentante' => $nomeRepresentante,
                                                'telefoneRepresentante' => $telefoneRepresentante,
                                                'rgRepresentante' => $rgRepresentante,
                                                'cpfRepresentante' => $cpfRepresentante,
                                                'cepRepresentante' => $cepRepresentante,
                                                'enderecoRepresentante' => $enderecoRepresentante,
                                                'pacote' => $pacote,
                                                'cursos' => $cursos,
                                                'clausulas' => $clausulas));
return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

Porém não estou conseguindo quebrar a página direto do html utilizando o `<pagebreak />`

```
[...]    
<div class="item w-100">
       <div class="item-titulo w-20">CPF:</div>
       <div class="item-conteudo">{{$cpfRepresentante}}</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<hr>
@endif
<pagebreak />
1.1 - Quando empregadas no presente contrato...
```

[image: Print do pdf não quebrando a página mesmo utilizando a tag]

O que posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ja tentou usando div com page-break-before do css?

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```

Antes de imprimir essa div, ele quebra a pagina e em seguida você pode imprimir o seu conteudo

Comment: Deu certo!! Obrigado!